# Laravel json column query to check if object exists

Tags: json, laravel

So I have a json column called `settings` in the table `companies` (which has a Laravel model called `Company`). That column may or may not contain an object called `business_key`. I try to return only the companies that contain this object. 
My query looks like this:

```
$owners = \Company::where('settings->business_key')->get();
```

I don't know how to make something like this work. I did not find anything Laravel specific for this. 
Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: If you have no default value for that column, it will be null in case of no business key. So, retrieve all column with not null business key

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are casting the field as an array in the model, you can treat it like other larval fields, so your query would be:

```
$owners = \Company::whereNotNull('settings->business_key')->get();
```

Comment: Hey, I have a problem too, in my case I have an JSON array of roles like ["user", "admin", "customer"] in this case how can I do a where clause for if a user is an admin?

Comment: So I figured it out, a simple Model::whereJsonContains["roles", "user"] fixed it...Yaaaay!

Answer (score 1):

In the purpose to retrieve all not null data, you can try this :

```php
$owners = \Company::whereRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(settings, "$.business_key") <> CAST("null" AS JSON)')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$data = \Company::whereNotNull('setting')->get();
```

If `setting` column contains no object then value will be `NULL`, then above query gives all records with objects in `setting` column. See docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)